# How to change the mailserver information displayed in cPanel

Tags: cpanel, mandrill, email-client, whm, mail-server

When I setup a new cPanel account for a client (through WHM), I also setup a Mandrill account for clients to use as their mailserver.

Is it possible to change the mailserver information that is displayed in the "Configure Email Client" section of cPanel, and add their Mandrill details, instead?

[image: This section]

Comment: This is your server hostname, you can change it by whm=> hostname

Comment: and if you want  change port number than find exim setting and change it from there

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's a mess. The comments in this cPanel Feature Request thread may help you:

https://features.cpanel.net/topic/fix-incorrect-calculation-of-secure-mail-server-hostname

Comment: Really, it only made it muddier :)

Comment: Good news / bad news situation. Right now, it looks like there is no way to do this without stomping on your changes next time cPanel is updated. However, we're looking to do this exact thing right now, so if we come up with an answer, I'll post it here.